# Number theory - simple proof on proving an integer

Tags: number-theory

Let n,x be a Positive Integer.

**Prove x<sup>n</sup> is an integer**

This seems very simple. How do I prove this?

Comment: Use induction on $\,n,\,$ and use that the product of two integers is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pose $y_0 = 1$ and $y_i = xy_{i-1}$.

It's clear that if $y_{i-1}$ is an integer, then $y_i$ is also an integer.
Notice that $y_1 = x$ is an integer.

By induction, $y_n = x^n$ is an integer.